# Exclude subfolder for copy job with robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I have two sub-folders in my main folder in source, from those two sub-folders I wanted to copy only one folder to destination.

And I have many main folders like that, wanted to apply same logic to all main folders. Please help me with the appropriate command for this.

Source:

```
  ABC
        123
        456
  XYZ
        123
        456
```

Destination:

```
ABC
      123     (to be copied)
XYZ
      123      (to be copied)
```

(‘456’ folder should exclude)

Comment: You appear to have six directory names there, several of which are duplicates. Is that in some structure, e.g. with the numeric folders as sub-folders within the lettered ones?

Comment: This probably shouldn't have been migrated. As for the question itself, just define all 456 folders as exclusions.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you looking to not copy  any folder with a certain name, or only if it's the first child? Or do you only want folder 123 when it's the child folder

Answer (score 6):

Use robocopy's `xd` parameter to exclude folders; e.g. `robocopy source_folder destination_folder /xd 456`